# InCopy CS5 settings linger mysteriously somewhere

Tags: workspace, adobe-indesign, roaming-profiles

At work our team is stuck with an archaic version of InCopy (CS5 / 7.0.5) that won't be upgraded.

We have to "hotdesk". For a long time the PCs all had just local windows accounts with a common username and password. Every time you sat down at a PC it had the last person's InCopy workspace settings. You could reset the workspace to your preferences (everyone sets up their own), but some settings never seemed to be saved - specifically, the locations of individual SmartConnection panels, and the columns shown or hidden in those panels. But if you turned the PC off and went home for the day, then came in the next day, your settings would remain - so they must be saved somewhere.

We finally convinced the IT department to set up roaming profiles, hoping that wherever those settings were being stored on the local PCs would become part of the roaming user profile. They bought a bunch of shiny new expensive PCs and set up the profiles. But the InCopy settings for the location of the panels and the shown/hidden columns still don't stick. If you stay at one PC (ie. not roaming!), log off at the end of the day, come in the next day and sit down again, your settings remain. They must be saved somewhere. But if you move to a PC you've not used before, the settings are gone.

I've searched all the files on the system to see which show changes to the timestamp when the settings are changed in the application, or when the application is closed. The files that change are within the "roaming" data that is saved on the server. Nothing appears to be saved in the registry, either.

So where is this data being saved? How come when I power down the PC, go home, come back the next day and sit back down, my panel locations and column preferences are remembered, but if I log out, get up, turn on a different PC and log into it, my preferences are no longer there?

Any solution to this, or just information that may help, would be of great assistance to our whole team.

Comment: Unclear: Is InCopy only installed on one server and you are logging to it from another PC? If so, how (RDP etc)?

Comment: I think there's actually more than one server (one for backup/test) but in general we all log into one regular server for day to day use. Everyone has an individual login/account. The server is a physically separate machine. We log in at individual PC workstations that each have InCopy installed.

Comment: Logic says that if you are using a local version of InCopy, then the workspace data is stored locally, as you have been describing. [InDesign preferences and support files](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/indesign-preferences-support-file-locations.html) says "Local Cached Data Folder:  C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Local\Adobe\InDesign\Version [#]\en_US\Cache".

Comment: Thank you. I just tried changing the columns that are displayed in one of my SmartConnection panels, and then the location of one of the panels, and nothing seemed to change in there.

Comment: There might be other places not mentioned in the documentation. You will need to check the entire disk for that,

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my post I've given that a go. So I'm asking in the hope that someone else may have run across this (or something like it) before.